# Remove content from labels in different View Controllers with one button?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to remove the contents of two labels in two different View Controllers using one button in one of the two View Controllers?

Comment: Use `NotificationCenter`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use *delegate* or *notifications*.